# Question about the place of definition of the metric

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, curvature

I was reading the book "Dynamical Systems in Cosmology" of the author J. Wainwright. He says that, in order to  specify the space-time geometry you need a Lorentzian metric $g$ defined on a manifold $M$.

I agree with that, but in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.04604) (to be specific, above the equation number (5)) they define the metric over a domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^{d}$, is this right?

I was thinking that this could only work if you have a flat space-time.

Comment: When I hear the word manifold I associate it with  a topological space which locally looks Euclidean but allows for additional structure. When I hear the word domain I associate it with a function and an interval. I can't say if the it's right or wrong - and I don't have time to read the paper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Locally, there is no problem. The neighborhood $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{R}^d$ of the chart is only isomorphic to (a subset of) the manifold. The neighborhood $\Omega$ imports the metric (and curvature) from the manifold via the isomorphism. The standard flat metric on $\mathbb{R}^d$ plays no role in the construction.
2. Globally, there is a problem. The action principle in the [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.04604) does only describe spacetimes that are [homeomorphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism) to $\Omega$. One solution is to give up globally defined actions.